# Unity: Проблема с авторизацией в play game service

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play, google-play-services, unity3d-android

Проблема с авторизацией в play game service:
У меня выходит ошибка:

```
Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
Invoking callbacks, AuthState changed from silentPending to Unauthenticated.
AuthState == Unauthenticated calling auth callbacks with failure
```

**Вот мой код:**

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().EnableSavedGames().Build(); 
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config); 
PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true; 
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate(); 
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => { 
if (success) print("Удачно вошел"); 
else print("Неудачно вошел"); 
});
```

Всегда входит неудачно.
Идентификатор клиента я установил в юнити. Кейстор и алиасы создал. В плеймаркет сервис вбил кейстор. Название пакетов совпадают в игре и в консоли разработчика.
Я уже не знаю что делать. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Игра, я так понимаю, не зарелизена ещё, а лишь в драфте? Если так, то вы учётку свою в [тестеровщики добавили](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub)?

Comment: Игра не зарелизена. Учетку свою в тестировщики добавил. Пробовал загрузить версию и внедрить её и потом тестировать, также пробовал сразу в юнити через build & run запустить = итог тот же.

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов а в консоли точно OAuth 2.0 правильно настроен? https://console.developers.google.com/ SHA1 точно с релизного ключа, а не дебаг?

Comment: я этот SHA1 указал - http://joxi.ru/Y2LyOwDS93RwYA

Comment: я то еще не выпустил игру в свет, он еще во внутреннем тестировании находится

Comment: благодарю! оказывается еще нужно в самих игровых сервисах добавить в тестеры!